# Workmanager is not working when phone gets lock or in sleep mode

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a requirement. I need to track the user's location continuously for every 15 minutes. So I thought of using workmanager package. It is working fine when app is in foreground background and terminated state only if phone screen is on. When I lock the screen the workmanager periodic task is not getting excecuted.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:workmanager/workmanager.dart';

 var task = 'FIrstTask';
 @pragma('vm:entry-point')
 void callbackDispatcher() {
 Workmanager().executeTask((taskName, inputData) {
print('Hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii-------->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>$inputData["time"]');
return Future.value(true);
});
}

void main() async {
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
await Workmanager().initialize(callbackDispatcher, isInDebugMode: true);
runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
const MyApp({super.key});
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return const MaterialApp(
  title: 'Flutter Demo',
  home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
  );
  }
  }

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

final String title;

 @override
 State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
 }

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(widget.title),
  ),
  body: Center(
    child: TextButton(
        onPressed: () {
          var s = DateTime.now().millisecond;
          Workmanager().registerPeriodicTask(s.toString(), task,
              inputData: {"time": s.toString()},
              frequency: const Duration(minutes: 1),
              initialDelay: const Duration(seconds: 10),
              constraints: Constraints(networkType: NetworkType.connected));
        },
        child: const Text('Click me')),
  ),
  );
  }
  }
```